# One-hot encoding across multiple columns - but as one group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have a Python Pandas DataFrame :

```
Name Item1 Item2 Item3
John Sword
Mary Shield Ring
Doe  Ring Sword
```

Desired output :

```
Name Item-Sword Item-Shield Item-Ring
John   1           0             0
Mary   0           1             1
Doe    1           0             1
```

Is this any way to achieve this outside of manual processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with convert `Name` column to index and remove only missing values columns, then use `max` for only `0,1` values in output, add prefix and convert index to column:

```
df = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Name')
                     .dropna(axis=1, how='all'), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
       .max(axis=1, level=0)
       .add_prefix('Item-')
       .reset_index())
print (df)
   Name  Item-Ring  Item-Shield  Item-Sword
0  John          0            0           1
1  Mary          1            1           0
2   Doe          1            0           1
```

Alternative with `melt` and `crosstab` - @sammywemmy solution with `drop_duplicates`:

```
df1 = (df.melt("Name")
        .assign(value=lambda x: "Item-" + x.value)
        .drop_duplicates(['Name','value']))
df1 = pd.crosstab(df1.Name, df1.value)
print (df1)
value  Item-Ring  Item-Shield  Item-Sword
Name                                     
Doe            1            0           1
John           0            0           1
Mary           1            1           0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) + [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
new_df = (df.melt('Name').groupby(['Name', 'value'])
            .count()
            .clip(0, 1)
            .unstack('value', fill_value=0)
            .droplevel(0, axis=1)
            .add_prefix('Item-')
            .rename_axis(columns=None)
            .reset_index())
print(new_df)
```

Or [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)

```
df2 = df.melt('Name')
new_df = (df2.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='value', values='variable', 
                          aggfunc='any', fill_value=0)
             .astype(int)
             .add_prefix('Item-')
             .rename_axis(columns=None)
             .reset_index())
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
   Name  Item-Ring  Item-Shield  Item-Sword
0   Doe          1            0           1
1  John          0            0           1
2  Mary          1            1           0
```

Comment: check now:) @jezrael

Comment: yop, now better

Answer (score 0):

If you set your index to `"Name"`, and then `stack()` your data into a single `Series` you can use `pd.get_dummies` to encode the data. Then you'll need to use `max` to get the maximum value for each `"Name"` (this logic boils down to: we don't care if `"Mary"` has a ring as item 1 or item 2, so long as she has a ring). Once that's done, we can tidy up by adding a prefix and resetting our index back into the `DataFrame`

```
out = (df.set_index("Name")
       .stack()
       .pipe(pd.get_dummies)
       .max(level="Name")
       .add_prefix("Item-")
       .reset_index())

print(out)
   Name  Item-Ring  Item-Shield  Item-Sword
0  John          0            0           1
1  Mary          1            1           0
2   Doe          1            0           1
```